# C# SQL Update click event error: Incorrect syntax near ','

Tags: c#, sql-server

I can't seem to get past this System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException error. I am trying to update records that are already pulled into textboxes. I seem to only get one error at a time when I change something, and here is where I am at now:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Incorrect syntax near ','.

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // UPDATE / SAVE BUTTON
    using (SqlConnection con = new
        SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL1;Initial Catalog=EE; Integrated Security=True"))
    {

        string query = "UPDATE tbl_TextBoxes SET Ename, Sname, PositionUpdateBox, EvalDate, PerFac1, PerFac2, PerFac3, PerFac4, PerFac5," +
                                        "PerFac6, PerFac7, PerFac8, PerFac9, PerFac10, PerFac11, PerFac12, PerFac13, Rating1, Rating2, Rating3, Rating4, Rating5," +
                                        "Rating6, Rating7, Rating8, Rating9, Rating10, Rating11, Rating12, Rating13 VALUES @Ename, @Sname, @PositionUpdateBox," +
                                        "@EvalDate, @PerFac1, @PerFac2, @PerFac3, @PerFac4, @PerFac5, @PerFac6, @PerFac7, @PerFac8, @PerFac9, @PerFac10, @PerFac11," +
                                        "@PerFac12, @PerFac13, @Rating1, @Rating2, @Rating3, @Rating4, @Rating5, @Rating6, @Rating7, @Rating8, @Rating9, @Rating10," +
                                        "@Rating11, @Rating12, @Rating13 WHERE Id = @Id" ;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ename", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sname", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PositionUpdateBox", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac1", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac2", textBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac3", textBox8.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac4", textBox11.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac5", textBox12.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac6", textBox13.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac7", textBox14.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac8", textBox15.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac9", textBox16.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac10", textBox17.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac11", textBox18.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac12", textBox19.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerFac13", textBox20.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EvalDate", textBox31.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating1", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating2", textBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating3", textBox10.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating4", textBox22.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating5", textBox23.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating6", textBox24.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating7", textBox25.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating8", textBox26.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating9", textBox27.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating10", textBox28.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating11", textBox29.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating12", textBox21.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rating13", textBox9.Text);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Evaluation Saved");
    }
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your UPDATE syntax is wrong.  Should be `UPDATE TABLE SET ColumnName1 = @Value1, ColumnName2 = @Value2, ColumnName3 = @Value3 `

Comment: I would also suggest cleaning up your Query to convert into a Stored procedure and use Parameterized query's properly also there are tons of documentation / tutorials / examples on how to construct a proper Update statement. this could have been found if you did a simple google search

Comment: @MikeChristensen - honest, I was writing my answer as you wrote your comment ;)

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already)

Comment: It was the UPDATE syntax that was wrong, but I also went wrong by calling "Id" after WHERE instead of the "Ename." Once I changed both of them, it worked. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

The format of your update statement is incorrect.

It should be

```
UPDATE tbl_TextBoxes SET
column1 = @value1,
column2 = @value2
WHERE Id = @Id
```